# Reloading page makes heavy load on the server

Tags: javascript, php

I made a counter in my admin panel to get the number of (new orders,new comments) and call it with interval time but it seem to make the server crashes frequently so if there a better idea to implement it.

```
   <a >
        <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
        <span>Orders</span><span class="label label-danger pull-right mail-info" id="ordernumber"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="new-orders.php"><span>New orders</span> <span class="label label-theme  mail-info" id="ordernumber1"></span></a>            
        </li>
        <li><a href="confirmed-orders.php">Comfirmed orders</a></li>
        <li><a href="finished-orders.php">finished orders</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<script>
setInterval(function(){
    $('#ordernumber').load("include/ordercount.php").fadeIn("slow");
    $('#ordernumber1').load("include/ordercount.php").fadeIn("slow");
},1500);
</script>
```

and this is the ordercount.php

```
<?php 

require_once('databaseCon.php');
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * From orders WHERE order_state=?");
$stmt->execute(array('pending'));
$count=$stmt->rowCount();
if($count>0)
    echo $count;
?>
```

Comment: You dont USE any of the selected columns from a `select *` so do a `select count()` instead save all that data going in and out of the database and up and down the wire

Comment: And do you REALLY need to know this information refreshed every 1.5 seconds? Thats a little excesive. Maybe change that from 1500 to 60000 and get it once a minute, then make it 300000

Comment: do you also have a index on your order_state? It will improve also speed

Comment: you could try this by using sockets. Here is a repo for using sockets with PHP [elephant.io](https://github.com/wisembly/elephant.io).